# WinAPI. How to get Hard Drive free/busy space

Tags: c, winapi

I'm writing a program for getting some of the hard drive information. At the moment, i was able to get the full size of the hard disk using the **DeviceIoControl** function and corresponding **IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY** flag .

I'm tried to use **GetDiskFreeSpace** function and send the **"\\.\PhysicalDrive0"** argument, but it doesn't work.

```
BOOL bResult = GetDiskFreeSpace("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", &dwSectorsPerCluster,
                   &dwBytesPerSector, &dwNumberOfFreeClusters,
                   &dwTotalNumberOfClusters);

if (bResult == FALSE) {
  std::cout << "Can't retrieve disk free space info." << std::endl;
  return bResult;
}
```

Output: Can't retrieve disk free space info.
For example, "\\.\PhysicalDrive0" replaced on "C:" work fine.

The question is how to get the free or used space on hard drive using WinAPI functions?

**P.S. Without using WMI.**

Comment: Yes. But it is not important to be a free or a busy space, if i know 1 of the parameters and full size, I can calculate the parameter 2.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work." mean? Show your code, show the output / outcome of that code and discuss how that output / outcome is different to what you want / need. The basics of technical communication apply here just as much as anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GetDiskFreeSpace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa364935%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) does "work", but you need to use the correct first parameter.

> `lpRootPathName [in]`
>
> The root directory of the disk for which information is to be returned.

`"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0"` is incorrect, because this is for the whole disk drive and it is not mounted by file system. However, this request is handled by file system. You need to use names like `"\\\\?\\c:\\"` or `"\\\\?\\Harddisk0Partition<N>\\"` or `"\\\\?\\HarddiskVolume<N>\\"` or `"\\\\?\\Volume{guid}\\"` - slash on the end is very important - without it will not work. But in case of `"\\\\?\\PhysicalDrive0\\"` - slash will not help. It will not work, because no FS is mounted on this device.

Comment: Ok. It's my fault in question. I just wanted to show that this function does not suit me. I should get information about free space of whole HDD, not 1 partition or volume.

Comment: @johnbrovi what you mean under free space on whole HDD ? free space exist only from file system view. whole HDD is not mounted by file system. only separate partition. you simply not understand what is "free space"

Comment: This *Disk Management* management console snap-in does show free space in a disk, even if that space isn't mounted, formatted, or part of a partition or volume. Your assertion that free space only exists when there is a file system isn't accurate.

Comment: @IInspectable - what is you mean under free space when disk(partition) is not formatted by any FS ?  from disk view exist only sectors/clusters. "free" senseless here. only from FS view exist sense say about free or used cluster.  disk can have several partitions. for every separate partition, if it formatted by some FS, exist sense speak about free/used space. for whole disk - no sense speak about this. need understand different between whole disk ( `\\.\PhysicalDrive0` ~aka~ `\Device\Harddisk0\DR0`) and `\Device\Harddisk0\PartitionX`

Comment: Ok then, another example: You install an OS, where the installer allows you to partition your disk along the way. It will show you free, unallocated space. There doesn't need to be a filesystem on a disk to know the raw capacity, that isn't in use. In fact, when you buy a new disk, without any partition or data on it, it will have a tag telling you about the capacity (i.e. the free space on it).

Comment: @IInspectable - sorry we speak about free space (in FS sense) or capacity ? this is different things. or you mean "free space" == "capacity"  ? disk of course have capacity. but how i understand question - johnbrovi want get exactly "free space" in FS sense. capacity he already get